# How to subscribe to the event?

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

I will point out at the beginning that I am just learning C# and Events.

I have the primary Main class of the program, which also creates a Form. In that class I create an object of class A. In class a I create an object of class B.

In class B I have an Event defined and I would like to make an EventHandler subscribe to it from the Main class (the purpose is to display in TextBox the text passed from the Event). How to do it?

In tutorials about Events is usually shown example of two classes, in one class is created an object from second class and for example, this event subscription in class level A for object of class B looks like this :
`b.OnMultipleOfFiveReached += b_MultipleOfFiveReached;`

I am very asking for help.

EDIT:

Form class:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        private ClassA _ClassAObject;
        public Form1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Form!");

            InitializeComponent();

            _ClassAObject = new ClassA();

            // It is IMPOSSIBLE to register Form handler to Class B event (no access to Class B object here):
            //_ClassBObject.OnLogEntry += Form_OnLogEntryHandler;
        }

        public void Form_OnLogEntryHandler(object sender, LogEntryEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Event Handler in Form! Log entry: " + e.LogEntry);
            this.textBox1.Text = e.LogEntry;
        }

    }

}
```

Class A:

```
using System;

namespace TestApp
{
    public class ClassA
    {
        private ClassB _ClassBObject;
        public ClassA()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Class A Object!");

            _ClassBObject = new ClassB();
            // It is possible to register Class A handler to Class B event:
            _ClassBObject.OnLogEntry += ClassA_OnLogEntryHandler;
            _ClassBObject.StartProcess();
        }

        public void ClassA_OnLogEntryHandler(object sender, LogEntryEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Event Handler in Class A object! Log entry: " + e.LogEntry);
        }
    }
}
```

Class B:

```
using System;

namespace TestApp
{
    public class ClassB
    {
        // declaring an event
        public event EventHandler<LogEntryEventArgs> OnLogEntry;

        public ClassB()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Class B Object!");
        }

        public void StartProcess()
        {
            OnLogEntry?.Invoke(this, new LogEntryEventArgs("#1 Example Log Entry"));
        }

    }

    public class LogEntryEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public LogEntryEventArgs(String iLogEntry)
        { LogEntry = iLogEntry; }
        public String LogEntry { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add some code in the body of the question in addition to or in place of the requirements text, please?

Comment: I have now added. Sorry it wasn't there before.

Answer (score 1):

If the instance of B is exposed by A, e.g. you have a MyB property with a public getter, and a is your A var inside Main you can simply write `a.MyB.OnMultipleOfFiveReached += b_MultipleOfFiveReached;`.

If this is not the case and the instance of B in class A is private you have to define another event in A which is triggered when the event in B is triggered. Something like this:

```
public class B
{
    public event EventHandler OnMultipleOfFiveReached;
}

public class A
{
    private B b;

    public event EventHandler OnMultipleOfFiveReachedInB;

    public A()
    {
        b = new B();
        b.OnMultipleOfFiveReached += B_OnMultipleOfFiveReached;
    }

    private void B_OnMultipleOfFiveReached(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (OnMultipleOfFiveReachedInB != null)
            OnMultipleOfFiveReachedInB(sender, e);
    }
}
```

At this point in Main you can write `a.OnMultipleOfFiveReachedInB += b_MultipleOfFiveReached;`.

Comment: What is the best approach if I want to create TextBox entries in the GUI from different places in the application, also when there will be more classes? It would be ideal as I wouldn't have to do such layered Events. And as if it would be possible to do it with one line in different places, like `OnLogEntry?.Invoke(this, new LogEntryEventArgs("#1 Example Log Entry"));`.

Comment: It seems to me that you are trying to implement some sort of binding between class A and its contents and a Form. I would keep it simple and expose B but I don't think there are a right and a wrong way to do it. I don't understand what you mean with the "one line in different places" question.